# Flipping image vertically

Tags: image

I'm trying to flip an image vertically (in C). This is what I've done so far. I think it works in theory, but when I run it I get segmentation fault. I somehow managed to fix this error a few days ago, but I didn't save it. This function that you see gives segmentation fault when I try to run. Is there a way to fix it so that it doesn't give that error and flips an image vertically?

```
void vertical( uint8_t array[], 
            unsigned int cols, 
            unsigned int rows )
{
   unsigned int top = 0;
   unsigned int bottom = rows-1;
   for(int r = 0; r < cols; r++)
{
   while(top != bottom && bottom > top)
    {
      int index1= r * cols + top;
      int index2= r * cols + bottom;

      int temp= array[index1];
      array[index1]= array[index2];
      array[index2] = temp;        
      bottom++;
      top++;
    } 

      top =0;
      bottom= rows-1;
 } 

}
```

Comment: Is `r` the row or the column?

Comment: Should it not be `r * top + cols` instead of `r * cols + top`? Your code probably flips it horizontally.

Comment: `bottom++;` -> `bottom--;` :D

Comment: From debugging this code with a 2 by 2 array I can see that `top` becomes 2123 and `bottom` becomes 2124... I.e. the inner loop iterates over 2000 times. What @anishsane said.

Comment: I agree with both of @anishsane's comments. Your segmentation fault is probably because you were calling `bottom++` so often that you went beyond the program's memory. Also you should have `r < rows` in your `for` loop.

Comment: I changed "r * top + cols" to "r * cols + top" and also "bottom++" to "bottom--" (this one was a typo, oops). I also changed the for loop to r < rows. I'm no longer getting the segmentation fault error, but the final image is not properly flipped. I just see random pixels. What did I do wrong?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be cols instead of rows since we're dealing with columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int index1= r * cols + top;` is off since top is a row, it should be multiplied by the number of columns, and r is the current column being flipped. so it should be `int index1 = top * cols + r;`. however `r` is a confusing name since it is a column index.

As others have commented bottom should be decremented in the loop.
`--bottom;` to avoid indexing outside the array bounds which would have caused the segfault.

This condition  `while(top != bottom && bottom > top)` is equivalent to `while (bottom > top)`.

It's usually best (in C) to iterate the columns in a row first since C is row-major and it simplifies the code here also and allows you to avoid computing the index from scratch. Each outer iteration moves down/up an entire row by adding/subtracting the number of columns in a row.

```
void vertical(uint8_t array[], unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows) {
   int top = 0;
   int bottom = (rows - 1) * cols;

   while (top < bottom) {

     for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
       int temp = array[top + c];
       array[top + c] = array[bottom + c];
       array[bottom + c] = temp;
     }

     top += cols;
     bottom -= cols;
   }
}
```